# Is it possible to post message to facebook when the app is running in background

Tags: iphone, facebook, background

I'm using facebook API. I want to submit some message to facebook when the app is running in the background. The problem is every time user request or submit a message to facebook, there will show a popup Webview. User need to click it again. So I want to skip this view and submit message in the background . Is this Possible?  Can anyone give some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply request `publish_stream` permissions from the user and then you can post on the user's behalf at any time, even when the user is not actively using your app (of course this is from a previous user request to have something posted on their behalf).  Once you have `publish_stream` then do an HTTP POST to `http://graph.facebook.com/USERID/feed?access_token=AppAccessToken` with a message post parameter of the message to be posted to their feed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah, I enabled location. Now it works.  I am now using this method : requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed", it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, application can not do anything but reciving notifications and presenting pushnotifycations during being in background. The only thing you can - is to ask user "open application rught now to post message to facebook" or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah, I enabled location. Now it works.  I am now using this method : requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed", it works. Thanks again.